# Proper way to access variable from activity within Service

Tags: android, android-activity, service

In my activity, there's a variable (*objectList*) which I would like to access from a Service (*TestService*):

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
     List<MyObject> objectList;

     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
     {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        startService( new Intent( getBaseContext(), TestService.class ) 
     );
}
```

And I have a skeleton for the Service:

```
public class TestService extends Service
{
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent)
    {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate()
    {
        super.onCreate();
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand( Intent intent, int flags, int startId )
    {
        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy()
    {
        super.onDestroy();
    }
}
```

My goal is to loop through every item in the *objectList* from the *TestService* every x seconds, process some data, and then update this particular item with new data.

The *MyObject* class has a lot of properties which I need to update. What is the proper way to pass the *objectList* from *mainActivity* to the *TestService* so I can work with the object list directly? Thanks!

Comment: You may do it, but you should not access Activity variables directly from the Service, instead you should use a BroadcastReceiver to update the List (or UI)  from the service or pass the list to the service directly if it is not UI update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By maintaining a reference to an `Activity` in a `Service`, you introduce a memory leak since you prevent the system from garbage collecting the `Activity` when the view is destroyed as a result of the `Activity` progressing through its lifecycle.

Instead, you should communicate the changes made by the `Service` to the `Activity` using a `BroadcastReceiver` as explained by @NongthonbamTonthoi in the comment. Basically the `Activity` should instantiate a `BroadcastReceiver` that listens for a specific type of broadcasts (identified by a unique key defined by you) which are sent by the `Service` whenever it performs an update.

Furthermore, I suggest that you move the list so that it is stored in the `Service` and then make the `Activity` retrieve the list from the `Service` by *binding* to the `Service` and then invoking a method defined in your `IBinder` implementation (an instance of which should be returned from `onBind(Intent)`). This way you can confine all code that makes changes to your model to the `Service` and keep the `Activity` as a (dumb) view that simply renders the model. Morover, with this design, you can make your list outlast the `Activity` by also *starting* the `Service` (note: *in addition to* binding to it) so that you can retain the state of your list even if your `Activity` is destroyed (e.g., as a result of your application being put to the background). If you choose this design, the broadcast sent by the  `Service` can simply be a notification that the list has changed, and the `Activity` can then retrieve the updated list by invoking the `getList` method specified in your `IBinder` implementation.

Comment: Thank you very much! Quick question, since I'm loading this list from the storage and new items to the list are added through the activity, I would simply make the service load the list from storage, correct? In addition, I'm passing the list to RecyclerView.Adapter from activity, I would simply fetch it via broadcast, correct? I'm confused if the list I would receive from Service broadcast is a 'reference' or 'copy'? Thank you!

Comment: Can you please explain this step in more detail: " the Activity can then retrieve the updated list by invoking the getList method specified in your IBinder implementation" Does that mean I'm not going to send the list over a broadcast, but instead the service will have a public method that activity will be able to access? Thanks!

Comment: It's up to you if you decide to return a reference to the list in the service or a copy (or even an unmodifiable view of the list); that all comes down to what you decide to return from the `getList` method of your `IBinder` implementation. I suggest you take a look at what the developer guide has to say about service binding. In short, you return an implementation of `IBinder` from your service's `onBind`. That implementation should define a method, `getList`, that the Activity can use to retrieve the list. Note: you'll have to cast the returned `IBinder` to your user defined type.

Comment: Thank you very much for your time and guidance!